# OpenGl play .obj file and animate individual objects of skeleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, opengl-shader-builder

I m trying to work on some animation which has to be played from the .OBJ and .MTL file. using OPENGL objective c

Having and animation of person/man walking in .obj need to render animation.

Im able to render the .OBJ file and move complete man but unable to move individual parts like hand or legs?

Please help me if any solution or and other approach that can do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How you have achieved this: Im able to render the .OBJ file and move complete man but unable to move individual parts like hand or legs?